# Laravel One submit button and two different post actions

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-5

Currently I have three different pages for invoice, checkout, and payment but I want to combine invoice & checkout.

Currently this is invoice (not showing all the fields for both forms)

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/invoice')) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('totalTax', $sumTax) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('total', $sumTotal) !!}
```

This is checkout. As you can see it posts to the payment services site

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="https://example.com/secure/processpayment.php">
<input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="{!! $invoice->Id !!}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="{!! Auth::user()->id !!}"/>
```

The invoice controller currently redirects to the checkout page with some data after processing the invoice data. I will still need to pass invoice data like `$sumTotal` and `$sumTax` to the payment service

```
    return view('checkout')->with(['invoice' => $invoice]);
```

How can I make it so that both of these forms are on one page and when you click submit the invoice form data goes to the invoice controller and the checkout form posts to the payment services site? It would be great if somebody could provide an example

Comment: Make them both into a single form, then sort where to send the data in the controller.

Comment: How can I post to `action="https://example.com/secure/processpayment.php` in the controller?

Comment: You wouldn't, post one form with all the data to a single route. `/invoice` for example.. Then either refactor the code in processpayment.php into your controller, or send a post request via curl with the necessary data.